# S3 API for SMB File Share

Tags: c#, file-io, amazon-s3, cloud

I have a couple of machines in the house which each have varying amounts of disk space, and i would like to make these accessible via an S3 compatible API. I have found many tools that will convert S3 into an SMB file share or into a Windows/Linux/OSX drive, but nothing that does it the other way around.

Are there any examples of implementing an S3 compatible API that uses a disk or file share as a backing store? I am not too worried about redundancy (have already looked at OpenStack, but for my needs it seems over kill). I'm a .NET Dev, so C# code would be preferable, but even code in another language to see how to implement a compatible API may help.

[Clarification: I know lots of people are looking at moving their storage out of house and use S3 as one of the main storage systems, but some of our clients need the data stored in house due to legal reasons or speed issues. Implementing something that would use the same API for either S3 or an In-house system, backed by a SAN, would be handy.]

Answer (score 2):

I found the following Java based project, [s3proxy](https://github.com/andrewgaul/s3proxy), which proxies S3 requests to a few different providers, file system included. I have not fully tried it out yet, but its a start to where i want to go, meaning i dont have to manage my own API and keys for storage...

Answer (score 0):

I understand the reasons for you doing this but I urge caution.

Rather than using the S3 as an interface to storage in your application, I'd suggest that create an abstract API that will act as the interface to storage. In this way you can create any adaptor underneath that will connect to any sorge API you like - local disk/remote disk/db/S3/Azure etc etc.

This I believe is a better architectural pattern than the one you're proposing. The Beauty is many fold. The first is that you get your 'I don't care where storage is' code. The second is that you've freed yourself from the constraint OF S3 as you can add any feature you like on top of S3 without your code being affected. Another benefit is that you can probably find good pre written code for all the different stores you want to work with.

Comment: yea, that's what i was working on at the moment... all file reads and writes go though an API which then, in turn, talks to a Windows Service which then writes to SMB, but that Windows Service, or even the API, could talk anywhere. But it is a very "custom" service... being able to get anything that usually talks to S3 (CyberDuck comes to mind) to talk to our file share may be handy. plus it means we dont have to implement the API.